# If greater than shipping weight check

Tags: javascript, if-statement, return-value

I am trying to get new website off the ground through bigcommerce and found out they don't have anything for freight shipping. I know enough to identify my problem and the code that needs changed within the template file but not create code to do what I want. Currently shipping is calculated at checkout and displays "Calculated at checkout" The block of code displaying the shipping is

```
    <div class="DetailRow" style="display: %%GLOBAL_HideShipping%%">
        <div class="Label">%%LNG_Shipping%%:</div>
        <div class="Value">
           %%GLOBAL_ShippingPrice%%
        </div>
    </div>
```

I need the line %%GLOBAL_ShippingPrice%% which makes "Calculated at checkout" appear only on items under 150lbs and for items greater than 150lbs the message "Contact us for a shipping quote". Weight is currently generated in the listing by the a block of code in the same file reading.

```
    <div class="DetailRow" style="display: %%GLOBAL_HideWeight%%">
        <div class="Label">%%LNG_Weight%%:</div>
        <div class="Value">
            <span class="VariationProductWeight">
                %%GLOBAL_ProductWeight%%
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

It seems %%GLOBAL_ProductWeight%% is what probides the weight displayed but it reads "xyz LBS" and since it adds LBS to the number I'm not sure how to write code to check the return as greater or less than 150 or how to get it to then display the correct message. If any additional information is needed to create a code to do this let me know and I will provide it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "replace" js function to remove the "LBS" string from your text.

```
(function getCorrectTextBasedOnWeight() {

var weightSpanElements = document.getElementsByClassName('VariationProductWeight');

var answerMessageSpan = document.getElementById('answerMessage');

for (var i = 0; i < weightSpanElements.length; ++i) {
    var item = weightSpanElements[i];
    var weightValue = item.innerHTML.replace("LBS", "");
    if (weightValue <= 150) {
        answerMessageSpan.innerHTML = "Calculated at checkout";
    } else {
        answerMessageSpan.innerHTML = "Contact us for a shipping quote";
    }

    }
})();
```

You can use this sample in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/amontellano/YdV4S/

Simply change the value inside of the span of the HTML section and you will see how the answerMessage display the correct text based on weight value.

Comment: I thank you for your help. It seems that I can't get it to work correctly on the page where it's supposed to display. I replaced the line %%GLOBAL_ShippingPrice%% with the provided code but I seem to be getting either the entry back as a string of text with no formatting or the spot remains blank. I know I must be doing something wrong but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Hi. I think it is not so easy as replacing the line %%GLOBAL_ShippingPrice%% with the provided code. The code was showed as a sample of logic to handle what you need. If you are not familiarized with your code I would suggest ask for someone else's help with your application code personally.

Comment: I think i will do that as it's a template file provided by bigcommerce and not of my own creation. I know that I can replace %%GLOBAL_ShippinPrice%% with standard text to get it to display on the line I want but how I get it to perform the check and provide the desired text may take more than I'm capable of. Thanks for the help I believe that this points me more in the direction I need to head.